# Object selection in viewport in 2.82

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools

I've been using Blender for decades, and like many, I am sure, I had a hard time adapting to the changes introduced in 2.8. It's going much more smoothly now, after having to relearn a few things, and am quite happy with the way things are now.

I am having a very nasty problem though, and I can't seem to unlearn the way I've been doing things. In 2.82, I am somehow unable to select object in the viewport (orthographic, wireframe, with the right click select enabled, because how to ever unlearn that !). It seems to be related to that X-ray setting in the viewport option. It has to be disabled (or perhaps enabled and set to 0 ?) in order for me to select any object (mesh, it looks like empties, cameras, lights, etc... still work), and I think I'm just used to having no occlusion in the wireframe viewport, previous version were always see-through. I'm not having any problem in edit mode, its really just in object mode. It feels super weird, I'm not sure on what I have to click to be able to select anything, it's erratic to say the least.

Am I supposed to just use the outliner from now on ? Am I doing something wrong ? It seemed more consistent in 2.81, but I'm not sure.

Sorry if this has been reported and discussed previously, I looked around and found related topics, but didn't seem to find any conclusive solution or the cause of the problem.

Many thanks.

Edit: [This topic](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/decoupling-x-ray-and-limit-selection-to-visible/3498) is the closest I've found - it doesn't look like there is a way to get the old behaviour back yet.

Comment: The thread you've linked is about selection in edit mode though, not object mode and how occluded geometry is treated. This is a different issue from yours. Clicking on objects should select them just fine in object mode.

Comment: Perhaps you're having the issue that's described in [T76684](https://developer.blender.org/T76684)?

Comment: This is a different issue altogether, it seems. I've managed to select anything in the viewport, but I had to get X-Ray on and alpha set to 1, meaning the objects intersect and occlude eachothers. I guess this works fine, although I would really prefer seeing through the objects. Note that I played with the viewport clip start and end, which didn't change anything.